# Stop Audio Loop Playback Based on Dynamic Audio Duration

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I have an audio cue that loops indefinitely. The idea is that for as long as the target actor is overlapping a sphere component, the audio will play indefinitely, randomly looping through audio waves. On end overlap, I would like the audio to stop, but complete the last loop.

I tried using the duration concept here with a Delay Stop node. (https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/getting-duration-of-audio-component-4-7/308302/6)

However, since the loop is set indefinitely, it will continue to play. Below is the audio cue and the blueprint snippet that runs it. The audio component is set as a variable on Begin Play as GlitchSounds.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIxC8.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.